# How to make 'Table option' dynamic in Copy activity in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a simple pipeline in Azure Data Factory that has a Copy Activity.

In the sink tab there is an option named 'Table Option'.

Now the question is, I want to make it dynamic means:- If the table is already available in sink then don't create any table and if there is not any table in the sink table then create a new table based on the source schema.
(I have multiple tables in source and half of them already created in sink and half of them are waiting to be created)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add create a script in Sink pre-copy-script.

Example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.test2', 'U') IS NULL SELECT * INTO dbo.test2 FROM dbo.test1 WHERE 1 = 0;
```

This script will create an empty table on the sink database based on the source table schema "dbo.test1".

[image]